# All users of a group can edit each others files (Linux)

Tags: linux, php, umask

I want anyone in group www-data to have write access to `/var/www`. For example, if 'a' and 'b' are in group www-data and 'a' creates a file in `/var/www` - then 'b' will be able to edit it.

The problem is that I create files that PHP and Apache can't edit - and they create files *I can't edit without sudo*. Both PHP and myself are in www-data group.

I changed the umask setting `/etc/profile` from `umask 022` to `umask 002`. Is this a safe and proper way to handle this?

**Update**: Even after changing /etc/profile and restarting the computer PHP still creates files with permission `-rw-r--r--`.

Comment: Have you set the sticky (sgid) bit on `/var/www`?

Comment: How do I set the sticky bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apache startup script resets everything when apache is started on Debian/Ubuntu.  On a Debian/Ubuntu system you should update your umask by adding your umask command to `/etc/apache2/envvars`.  You may also need to change the permissions on the directories under /var/www to 2775.  This will force new files that are created to be owned by the group that owns the directory instead of the default group for that user.

Comment: So would the command be `chmod -R 2775 /var/www`?

Comment: No: that would do the same to files as well as directories - a bad idea.  Try: `find /var/www -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 2775`; that only changes directories and deals with funny characters (blanks etc) in file names.

Comment: oops, I already ran it. xD

Comment: @Xeoncross: then I recommend running something like: `find /var/www -type f -print0 | xargs chmod 664`.  Most of the files under there should not be executable - possibly all (it depends where your cgi-bin directory is, for example).